# how to add text between handles in a range slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, rangeslider, nouislider

I am using `noUiSlider`, but in fact any range slider library would work.
I have a small widget (here: https://codepen.io/chapkovski/pen/pobRwZj) where people have to split the range into three sections:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider-color');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
  start: [6000, 12000],
  connect: [true, true, true],
  range: {
    'min': [2000],
    'max': [20000]
  }
});

var connect = slider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect');
var classes = ['c-1-color', 'c-2-color', 'c-3-color'];

for (var i = 0; i < connect.length; i++) {
  connect[i].classList.add(classes[i]);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.6.2/nouislider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.6.2/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .c-1-color {
    background: red;
  }
  
  .c-2-color {
    background: yellow;
  }
  
  .c-3-color {
    background: green;
  }
</style>
<div id='slider-color'></div>
```

What I can't figure is how to add a text within the ranges. For instance for the mid-range (yellow one) would be something like 'Second category: XX%' (depending on the handles position. When I do something like:

```
.c-3-color::after {
content:'my text goes here';
}
```

it ends up completely deformed.

Comment: I edited my answer I think it is more adapted to what you wish

Answer (score 1):

On the parent you are having scale so this is why it is growing. You need to compensate that with child or pseudo child Please have a look as below:

```
.c-3-color::after {
  content:'my text goes here';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 33%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(4,2);
}
```

### DEMO (with adjustment of the code above because line is smaller

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider-color');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
  start: [6000, 12000],
  connect: [true, true, true],
  range: {
    'min': [2000],
    'max': [20000]
  }
});

var connect = slider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect');
var classes = ['c-1-color', 'c-2-color', 'c-3-color'];

for (var i = 0; i < connect.length; i++) {
  connect[i].classList.add(classes[i]);
}
```

```css
.c-3-color::after {
  content:'my text goes here';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 33%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(3,2);
  font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.6.2/nouislider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.6.2/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .c-1-color {
    background: red;
  }
  
  .c-2-color {
    background: yellow;
  }
  
  .c-3-color {
    background: green;
  }
</style>
<div id='slider-color'></div>
```

Comment: that looks great. I wonder if there is any way to keep text 'normal' because now when you drag handles it stretches in and out

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can adapt that with js to adjust correct scale. Depending the length of the part.